# Как исправить код чтобы можно было скачать без входа в сайт?

Tags: php, wordpress

как исправить код чтобы можно было скачать без входа в сайт?

```
  <div class="property-document-link login-link">
                            
                            <?php if( $documents_download == 1 ) {
                                if( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $attachment_meta->guid ); ?>" target="_blank"><?php esc_html_e( 'Download', 'houzez' ); ?></a>
                                <?php } else { ?>
                                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-register-form"><?php esc_html_e( 'Download', 'houzez' ); ?></a>
                                <?php } ?>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $attachment_meta->guid ); ?>" target="_blank"><?php esc_html_e( 'Download', 'houzez' ); ?></a>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Сначала идет проверка на возможность скачивания `if( $documents_download == 1 )`, потом проверка того что пользователь залогинен `is_user_logged_in()`. Если оба условия выполняются то выводится ссылка на скачивание файла. Уберите проверки и оставте только вывод ссылки на скачивание файла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если убрать проверку на то, что пользователь залогинен, получается такой код:

```
<div class="property-document-link login-link">
    <?php if ( $documents_download == 1 ) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $attachment_meta->guid ); ?>"
           target="_blank"><?php esc_html_e( 'Download', 'houzez' ); ?></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $attachment_meta->guid ); ?>"
           target="_blank"><?php esc_html_e( 'Download', 'houzez' ); ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Смысла проверки в нём `$documents_download` ровно ноль. Выводится одно и то же. Но дальше уж вам решать, какой смысл имеет эта переменная `;documents_download` и что с ней делать.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Wonderlancer Если ответ принят, его стоит отметить галочкой внизу. Если информация в ответе полезна, можно нажать на стрелку вверх. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.